# Maui Picker Desing

Tags: c#, maui

I'm building a Maui app where I need to use a picker. I successfully use it and return the data, but the problem is that I can't change the design of the picker. I want the elements that are in the Picker backgroup color to be another color. The Cancel button should be in a different position, but I can't do it.

```
<Picker x:Name="picker"
        Title="Select a monkey">
  <Picker.ItemsSource>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
      <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
      <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
      <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
      <x:String>Squirrel Monkey</x:String>
      <x:String>Golden Lion Tamarin</x:String>
      <x:String>Howler Monkey</x:String>
      <x:String>Japanese Macaque</x:String>
    </x:Array>
  </Picker.ItemsSource>
</Picker>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you can open the `Styles.Xaml` under `Resources/Styles` and change the styles of controls. However, it will only change the styles of entry on the Picker when you set the `Backgroundcolor` and `TextColor`. If you want to change the styles of the dropdown, you can [customize control using handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/create?view=net-maui-7.0).

**On iOS:**

```
using UIKit;// using namespace
```

Handler

```
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.PickerHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("Custom",(Handler, view) =>  
        {  
#if IOS  
            UIPickerView pickerview = (UIPickerView)Handler.PlatformView.InputView;// get the native control of the dropdown  
            pickerview.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Cyan;// change BackgroundColor  
            pickerview.Delegate = new CustomPickerDelegate(PickerItemList);// invoke UIPickerViewDelegate to change the Text color, PickerItemList is the itemsource of Picker  
  
            var toobar = (UIToolbar)Handler.PlatformView.InputAccessoryView;  
            var donebutton = (UIBarButtonItem)toobar.Items[1];//  get the native control of the done button  
            donebutton.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UIStringAttributes()  
            {  
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red,  
                ForegroundColor = UIColor.Brown  
                 
            }, UIControlState.Normal);// change the styles  
#endif  
        });
```

UIPickerViewDelegate

```
  public class CustomPickerDelegate : UIPickerViewDelegate  
{  
    List<PickerItem> Items;  
    public CustomPickerDelegate(List<PickerItem> datasource)  
    {  
        Items = datasource;  
    }  
     
    [Export("pickerView:attributedTitleForRow:forComponent:")]  
    public Foundation.NSAttributedString GetAttributedTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)  
    {  
        PickerItem item = Items[(int)row];  
        var text = new NSAttributedString(item.ID.ToString(), font: UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(18), foregroundColor: UIColor.Green);  
        return text;  
    }  
}  

public class PickerItem  
{  
    public int ID { get; set; }// ItemDisPlayBinding of Picker  
  
}
```

Comment: Hi Jessie, you know how to change default style picker in Windows platform?

Comment: @Jessie Zhang -MSFT  In addition to iOS, how about on WinUI, Android, Mac?  Could you point us to any documentation on this>